# Why do I get this error when I run 'bower install'?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, middleman

I am using this [middleman](https://github.com/biblichor/middleman-blog-bootstrap-template) project and trying to run the bower install and get the following...

```
bower not-cached    git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~2.0
bower resolve       git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~2.0
bower not-cached    git://github.com/appleboy/normalize.scss.git#~2.1
bower resolve       git://github.com/appleboy/normalize.scss.git#~2.1
bower not-cached    git://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#~2.6.2
bower resolve       git://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr.git#~2.6.2
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=Connection refused
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could be a temporarily problem on Githubs side, did you try it again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar issue and was due my network had certain ports blocked. What I tried (and worked) was forcing git to use "https" connections instead of "git" ones. Hope it help:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. No idea how much this just helped me out ;)